# Collection view automatically jumps to first cell when editing another cell

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to input text to collection view cells, whenever I edit the 2nd cell, the collection view scrolls to the first cell while the keyboard is showing up, here's the settings on the storyboard:

[image]

[image]

and this is the code on text editing:

```
func addText() {
    let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: bounds.width * 0.75, height: bounds.height * 0.75)))
    textView.center = shapeView.center
    textView.delegate = self
    textView.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 32)
    shapeView.addSubview(textView)
    imageButton.removeFromSuperview()
    textButton.removeFromSuperview()
}

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == "\n" {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Can somebody tell me why the view scrolls automatically and how to disable that?

Comment: What code do you have in the textView delegate functions?

Comment: @Sam I added all the functions

Comment: @BrightFuture What actually you are trying to do? Are you using UITextView inside tableCell & trying to write in it.?

Comment: @dahiya_boy yes, I'm adding text in collection view cells and saving those text to core data

Comment: @BrightFuture If you have storyboard then why didn't add textView from storyboard instead of calling addText. Because it is easy to mentain the components from storyboard.

Comment: @dahiya_boy not when you need to dynamically change the content of the cell, such as showing buttons and adding images as well

Comment: Can you give me details what actually you r showing in your cell. I need final layout.

Comment: @BrightFuture in textViewDelegate you have added textfieldDelegate

Comment: @Maddy yeah indeed, I removed that but the problem is still there

Comment: You should use [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) and you not need to manage layout when keyboard appear or disappear!

Comment: @Lion I don' think I did try to manage it

Comment: @BrightFuture are you using horizonatal collection view

Comment: @Maddy yes I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, strangely, it's because the collection view has an extra large size, as you can see in the screenshot added, it's larger than the screen width on both iPhone and iPad.

Though I still don't know why this happens, I solved the problem by setting the leading and trailing constraints to the edges of `view`, instead of setting a fixed width.

Thanks to everyone for answering!

Comment: After hours of searching, this ended up being the answer. I was having the same problem when scrolling in a collection view on an Apple TV, can't believe there are no upvotes on this yet, since the answer is posted since 2017. Thanks for your help!